# Getting stale element exception while iterating over element loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Build an iterator to iterate through a WebElement List:

```
List<WebElement> rowElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement element : rowElements)
{
    List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (WebElement localElement : elements)
    {
        localElement.getText();// Next localElement is stale after select statement is run.**
        if (!localElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            Select newSelectElement = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")));
            newSelectElement.selectByValue("value to select");// This causes a page refresh through Ajax call.
            final WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ajaxStatusModalPanelContainer")));
        }
    } // inner "For" loop ends
}
```

So now the issue is:

If I try to perform any command on `localElement`, after the `select` action which generates `ajax` call. At this point after the click, the `localElement` is stale, and you cannot access it again, unless, you perform a whole new routine to locate it again using any of `By` call.

Is there any way to handle such condition and do something
 like  `WebElement.refresh()` to de-stale the current or next coming
 element. I am using `java` as code language.

Comment: where is your HTML codes? and can you please re-edit your indentation? it is hard to tell how much code it is inside your "for" loop

Comment: I have updated code body, kindly have a look.Here I am trying to iterate through td element which have select drop down, on select to any value page refreshers and for next coming td element application throws stale element exception.

Comment: I think your problem is with this line, localElement = driver.findElement(By.tag("select")); try using a different variable name, this variable name has been used at the beginning of your inner For loop.

Comment: I have tried changing element that does not solve the issue. I am editing the code as well, kindly have a look.

Comment: You need to re-lookup the element, because of the refresh it is now stale.

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4419

Comment: @virusrock, Thanks for the issue link, but I am still facing issue and in the mentioned link there is no possible solution given and also issue seems to fixed.

Comment: No there is a solution for this. as suggested by Jamie R, re look up for the element. That is one way to do so. However, if you are familiar with page object model (http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/) and if you can squeeze your logic inside a class, then it should work. Page factory creates proxy element that are not affected by page refreshes. Drop me a comment if you need more information.

Comment: @virusrocks Thanks for example link, I am using page object pattern for locating the element, the issue is after finding the element list, I am iterating over it here I am not looking up for element using page object variables.  If its possible could please give me small code example to locate the element within the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to fetch all the elements again after they go stale. Updating the `SELECT` is causing an update to the relevant elements so they go stale. You will then have to refetch them all.

If you will provide more details around your scenario and the relevant HTML, I may be able to help you rewrite your code to work properly.